# Overhead of AKKA actors: IPC actors vs. intra-JVM actors

Tags: scala, akka

I have a project that started as a conventional akka-actor system. Recently, I realized it would be beneficial to be able to upgrade and reboot certain modules without having to take the entire program offline and recompile the entire project. I refactored my project to have multiple "App" classes, then launch each App into a separate screen, and the two Apps communicate over a reliable proxy (pointing to 127.0.0.1).

I've had great results and am considering using this same method to break out some more modules, however I am concerned that there might be a significant performance hit if too many of my inter-actor messages are to actors on a different actor-system. I imagine when actors are communicating within a JVM, the message passed is simply a lock put on the memory where the message is stored, the memory address is passed to the new actor, and the new thread unlocks the message (no transfer/rewriting of data actually occurs). When sending the message to a different actor system, even though it is on the same machine, the actual message needs to get sent over the network interface and copied into memory on the new actor system.

Has anybody implemented this sort of loosely-coupled architecture within one machine, and if so, did you run into any performance problems, or what were your experiences?

Comment: FYI, Akka doesn't use locks when sending messages within the same VM.  Akka messages must be immutable so that they can be freely shared without copying within the same VM, that way locks—and their associated headaches—aren't needed.

Comment: Ah, thanks that makes total sense.